# Error: After Updating Angular Material Module

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have taken MOOC(Coursera Angular) and following it. Recently i have updated my npm since then am getting build errors. I have searched around the web but none of it solves my issue.

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-container.d.ts(10,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/wamp64/www/Coursera/Angular/Angular-Coursera/node_modules/@angular/cdk/portal"' has no exported member 'BasePortalOutlet'.
 node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-container.d.ts(10,45): error TS2305: Module '"C:/wamp64/www/Coursera/Angular/Angular-Coursera/node_modules/@angular/cdk/portal"' has no exported member 'CdkPortalOutlet'.
node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/accordion.d.ts(1,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/accordion'.
node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/expansion-panel.d.ts(10,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/accordion'.
node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/expansion-panel.d.ts(36,14): error TS2314: Generic type 'TemplatePortal<C>' requires 1 type argument(s).
node_modules/@angular/material/select/typings/select.d.ts(11,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/wamp64/www/Coursera/Angular/Angular-Coursera/node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay"' has no exported member 'CdkConnectedOverlay'.
node_modules/@angular/material/sidenav/typings/drawer.d.ts(15,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/wamp64/www/Coursera/Angular/Angular-Coursera/node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling"' has no exported member 'CdkScrollable'.
node_modules/@angular/material/snack-bar/typings/snack-bar-container.d.ts(10,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/wamp64/www/Coursera/Angular/Angular-Coursera/node_modules/@angular/cdk/portal"' has no exported member 'BasePortalOutlet'.
node_modules/@angular/material/snack-bar/typings/snack-bar-container.d.ts(10,45): error TS2305: Module '"C:/wamp64/www/Coursera/Angular/Angular-Coursera/node_modules/@angular/cdk/portal"' has no exported member 'CdkPortalOutlet'.
node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-body.d.ts(10,26): error TS2305: Module '"C:/wamp64/www/Coursera/Angular/Angular-Coursera/node_modules/@angular/cdk/portal"' has no exported member 'CdkPortalOutlet'.
node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-body.d.ts(62,15): error TS2314: Generic type 'TemplatePortal<C>' requires 1 type argument(s).
node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-label.d.ts(9,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/wamp64/www/Coursera/Angular/Angular-Coursera/node_modules/@angular/cdk/portal"' has no exported member 'CdkPortal'.
 node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab.d.ts(28,23): error TS2314: Generic type 'TemplatePortal<C>' requires 1 type argument(s).
src/app/app.module.ts(4,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/wamp64/www/Coursera/Angular/Angular-Coursera/node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MaterialModule'.
```

These are the errors am getting

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
```

If i remove the above line my code works fine but i need to continue with Angular Material as the course is based on this. A clear solution is appreciated as am not much familar with NPM packages. Thanks

My Package.JSON file

```
    {
  "name": "con-fusion",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^5.0.0-beta.13",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.8",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.7",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.8",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.102",
    "codelyzer": "^4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: see this https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't working, because you need to import the specific material modules you want to use. Easiest thing to do is consolidate them into one shared Material module like the following:

Then in your root module `app.module.ts` import your shared material module

`import{ MaterialModule } from ' ./material.module.ts';`

**material.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatStepperModule,
  } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
  ],
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

Comment: Hi Where do you want me to create the material.module.ts? In my Code structure or in node_modules folder?

Comment: Typically in most apps developers will have a ‘shared’ or ‘common’ directory where they keep all the apps shared modules, services, directives, etc... That would be the place for the Material Module. However, it’s your app, so do what makes the most sense for you. Not in Node_Modules directory though, that is reserved for dependencies and you should not keep your own code there.

Comment: I exactly done what you have told me to do. But still am getting the same error

Comment: Can you show your package.json and exactly how you import the module in your application?

Comment: I edited the question with my package.json file look into it. And myself had a shared folder to share the interfaces so i copied your code(material.module.ts) into that and am importing that into my app.module.ts.  This is how i import..                                              import { MaterialModule } from './shared/material.module';

Comment: Oh gosh, your Angular CDK is grossly outdated. Update `"@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",` to the latest version 5.2.4  and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: thanks allot it works perfectly now. I have updated to latest and i had to change my "md" tags into "MAT" as that is deprecated

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help. Happy coding! :)